# What is the Java 7 try-with-resources bytecode equivalent using try-catch-finally?

Tags: java, try-catch, bytecode

I'm trying to understand how the new [try-with-resources statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) works by recreating it using regular try-catch-finally statements. Given the following test class using Java 7 try-with-resources:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class TryWithResources {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(System.out)) {
            gzip.write("TEST".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How would you rewrite this class to use try-catch-finally statements which produces exactly the same bytecode as the try-with-resources statement produces? Also, same question when two resources are used, as in the following example:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class TryWithResources2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
            gzip.write("TEST".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: compile the class and then decompile with non 1.7 aware decompiler (any decompiler, pretty much). This will give you rough equivalent of pre-1.7 code.

Comment: To share valuable information with the community (see Jeff Atwood's blog, [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).

Comment: What's exactly valuable, besides (slightly misguided) INVOKE_DYNAMIC java7 offers nothing new.

Comment: @bestsss - even if you don't like Java 7, the information is valuable to other people who do.  Or who need that information irrespective of their views on the language.

Comment: @Stephen, the information is readily available in the first draft about try-with-resource (jsr 334), here for instance: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/enhancements-0.75-edr-oth-JSpec/ (this aint the very 1st, though). I just do not see anything valuable. As for java7: it indeed offers nothing new, even invoke_dynamic is available w/ java6... besides the hotspot version is newer than 6_29 and has some bugfixes for G1 GC.

Comment: @bestsss - 1) that source is not *definitive*.  It is / was a "work in progress" document, subject to change until Java 7 was released.  2) You may not see anything valuable in Dan's information, but others do (and so do I).  Go figure.  3)  You may be disappointed in Java 7, but it is hardly relevant to the issue of whether Q/A is a good way to share information, or whether this information is useful to people who don't share your view of Java 7.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the `TryWithResources` class, the following class produces equivalent bytecode as the try-with-resources:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class TryCatchFinally {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(System.out);
            Throwable gzipEx = null;
            try {
                gzip.write("TEST".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                gzipEx = t;
                throw t;
            } finally {
                if (gzip != null) {
                    if (gzipEx != null) {
                        try {
                            gzip.close();
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            gzipEx.addSuppressed(t);
                        }
                    } else {
                        gzip.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using Sun JDK 1.7.0, the bytecode and exception tables for the main method in both `TryWithResources` and `TryCatchFinally` classes is:

```
  stack=3, locals=6, args_size=1
     0: new           #2                  // class java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream
     3: dup           
     4: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream."<init>":(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V
    10: astore_1      
    11: aconst_null   
    12: astore_2      
    13: aload_1       
    14: ldc           #5                  // String TEST
    16: ldc           #6                  // String UTF-8
    18: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/String.getBytes:(Ljava/lang/String;)[B
    21: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.write:([B)V
    24: aload_1       
    25: ifnull        95
    28: aload_2       
    29: ifnull        48
    32: aload_1       
    33: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    36: goto          95
    39: astore_3      
    40: aload_2       
    41: aload_3       
    42: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    45: goto          95
    48: aload_1       
    49: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    52: goto          95
    55: astore_3      
    56: aload_3       
    57: astore_2      
    58: aload_3       
    59: athrow        
    60: astore        4
    62: aload_1       
    63: ifnull        92
    66: aload_2       
    67: ifnull        88
    70: aload_1       
    71: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    74: goto          92
    77: astore        5
    79: aload_2       
    80: aload         5
    82: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    85: goto          92
    88: aload_1       
    89: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    92: aload         4
    94: athrow        
    95: goto          103
    98: astore_1      
    99: aload_1       
   100: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/IOException.printStackTrace:()V
   103: return        
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
        32    36    39   Class java/lang/Throwable
        13    24    55   Class java/lang/Throwable
        13    24    60   any
        70    74    77   Class java/lang/Throwable
        55    62    60   any
         0    95    98   Class java/io/IOException
```

For the `TryWithResources2` class, the following class produces equivalent bytecode as the try-with-resources:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class TryCatchFinally2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Throwable baosEx = null;
            try {
                final GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
                Throwable gzipEx = null;
                try {
                    gzip.write("TEST".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    gzipEx = t;
                    throw t;
                } finally {
                    if (gzip != null) {
                        if (gzipEx != null) {
                            try {
                                gzip.close();
                            } catch (Throwable t) {
                                gzipEx.addSuppressed(t);
                            }
                        } else {
                            gzip.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                baosEx = t;
                throw t;
            } finally {
                if (baos != null) {
                    if (baosEx != null) {
                        try {
                            baos.close();
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            baosEx.addSuppressed(t);
                        }
                    } else {
                        baos.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The bytecode and exception tables for the main method in both `TryWithResources2` and `TryCatchFinally2` classes is:

```
  stack=3, locals=10, args_size=1
     0: new           #2                  // class java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream
     3: dup           
     4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream."<init>":()V
     7: astore_1      
     8: aconst_null   
     9: astore_2      
    10: new           #4                  // class java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream
    13: dup           
    14: aload_1       
    15: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream."<init>":(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V
    18: astore_3      
    19: aconst_null   
    20: astore        4
    22: aload_3       
    23: ldc           #6                  // String TEST
    25: ldc           #7                  // String UTF-8
    27: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/String.getBytes:(Ljava/lang/String;)[B
    30: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.write:([B)V
    33: aload_3       
    34: ifnull        114
    37: aload         4
    39: ifnull        61
    42: aload_3       
    43: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    46: goto          114
    49: astore        5
    51: aload         4
    53: aload         5
    55: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    58: goto          114
    61: aload_3       
    62: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    65: goto          114
    68: astore        5
    70: aload         5
    72: astore        4
    74: aload         5
    76: athrow        
    77: astore        6
    79: aload_3       
    80: ifnull        111
    83: aload         4
    85: ifnull        107
    88: aload_3       
    89: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
    92: goto          111
    95: astore        7
    97: aload         4
    99: aload         7
   101: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
   104: goto          111
   107: aload_3       
   108: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.close:()V
   111: aload         6
   113: athrow        
   114: aload_1       
   115: ifnull        185
   118: aload_2       
   119: ifnull        138
   122: aload_1       
   123: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.close:()V
   126: goto          185
   129: astore_3      
   130: aload_2       
   131: aload_3       
   132: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
   135: goto          185
   138: aload_1       
   139: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.close:()V
   142: goto          185
   145: astore_3      
   146: aload_3       
   147: astore_2      
   148: aload_3       
   149: athrow        
   150: astore        8
   152: aload_1       
   153: ifnull        182
   156: aload_2       
   157: ifnull        178
   160: aload_1       
   161: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.close:()V
   164: goto          182
   167: astore        9
   169: aload_2       
   170: aload         9
   172: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
   175: goto          182
   178: aload_1       
   179: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.close:()V
   182: aload         8
   184: athrow        
   185: goto          193
   188: astore_1      
   189: aload_1       
   190: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/io/IOException.printStackTrace:()V
   193: return        
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
        42    46    49   Class java/lang/Throwable
        22    33    68   Class java/lang/Throwable
        22    33    77   any
        88    92    95   Class java/lang/Throwable
        68    79    77   any
       122   126   129   Class java/lang/Throwable
        10   114   145   Class java/lang/Throwable
        10   114   150   any
       160   164   167   Class java/lang/Throwable
       145   152   150   any
         0   185   188   Class java/io/IOException
```

Answer (score 25):

According to section 14.20.3.1 of the Java Language Specification (JLS) for Java 7:

```
try (VariableModifiersopt R Identifier = Expression ...)
    Block
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    final VariableModifiers_minus_final R Identifier = Expression;
    Throwable #primaryExc = null;
    try ResourceSpecification_tail
        Block
    catch (Throwable #t) {
        #primaryExc = #t;
        throw #t;
    } finally {
        if (Identifier != null) {
            if (#primaryExc != null) {
                try {
                    Identifier.close();
                } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                    #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
                }
            } else {
                Identifier.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JLS goes into a lot more detail ... too much to reproduce here.

---

The Java 7 JLS chapter on try-with-resources is available in HTML form [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), and you can get the PDF version of the JLS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the JLS7 PDF link; I've been looking for a complete, updated spec.

Comment: Reference to language specification is a nice touch.