# I need an expert to make me understand what Java Throwable's addSuppressed does?

Tags: java, exception, throwable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JDK 1.7 Throwable `addSuppressed()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946661/jdk-1-7-throwable-addsuppressed-method)

So Java has a method in the [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed%28java.lang.Throwable%29)

```
public final void addSuppressed(Throwable exception)
```

And this is what it does:

> Appends the specified exception to the exceptions that were suppressed
>   in order to deliver this exception. This method is thread-safe and
>   typically called (automatically and implicitly) by the
>   try-with-resources statement.

..i'm puzzled at this , what is "specified exception to the exceptions that were suppressed
in order to deliver this exception." ?

Comment: Basically, the method just adds data to the "documentation" that goes with the exception.  When you print out the stack trace of the exception (see printStackTrace()) there may be a list of "suppressed" exceptions.  This adds to that list.

Comment: @HotLicks - Ah OK I think I'm understanding this better .  So there's a customized list of exceptions that you can suppress.. hmm let me study more. thanks!!

Comment: @mtk - Thanks for that link - it is quite depth/specific I'm going to study it though.. thanks!!

Comment: Adel, I don't fully understand it myself, but I think it's basically that a function will sometimes suppress several exceptions while handling one, and without this mechanism the information about those would be lost.  It's not that you can specify a list of exceptions to automatically suppress.

Comment: @HotLicks - Hmm yes, that makes sense; and I will keep studyin til I get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty good explanation in the docs: [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed%28java.lang.Throwable%29)

> The suppression behavior is enabled unless disabled via a constructor.
>   When suppression is disabled, this method does nothing other than to
>   validate its argument.
>
> Note that when one exception causes another exception, the first
>   exception is usually caught and then the second exception is thrown in
>   response. In other words, there is a causal connection between the two
>   exceptions. In contrast, there are situations where two independent
>   exceptions can be thrown in sibling code blocks, in particular in the
>   try block of a try-with-resources statement and the compiler-generated
>   finally block which closes the resource. In these situations, only one
>   of the thrown exceptions can be propagated. In the try-with-resources
>   statement, when there are two such exceptions, the exception
>   originating from the try block is propagated and the exception from
>   the finally block is added to the list of exceptions suppressed by the
>   exception from the try block. As an exception unwinds the stack, it
>   can accumulate multiple suppressed exceptions.
>
> An exception may have suppressed exceptions while also being caused by
>   another exception. Whether or not an exception has a cause is
>   semantically known at the time of its creation, unlike whether or not
>   an exception will suppress other exceptions which is typically only
>   determined after an exception is thrown.
>
> Note that programmer written code is also able to take advantage of
>   calling this method in situations where there are multiple sibling
>   exceptions and only one can be propagated.

Comment: Thank   you i'm studying! !!!  Any elaboration ?