# How can I pass a collection of exceptions as a root cause?

Tags: java, exception

Some method, `myMethod`, invokes several parallel executions and awaits their terminations.

These parallel executions can finish with exceptions. So `myMethod` gets an exception list.

I want to pass the exception list as a root cause, but the root cause might be only a single exception. Sure I can create my own exception to achieve what I want, but I want to know if Java, Spring, or Spring Batch has something like this out of the box.

Comment: .NET has an `AggregateException` which contains a list of exceptions. That idea should be applicable to Java, too.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8946661/821436

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd do it (though given the JavaDoc I couldn't tell you why I hesitate), but there is the list of suppressed exceptions on `Throwable`, which you can add to via [`addSuppressed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)). The JavaDoc doesn't seem to say this is only for the JVM to use in try-with-resources:

> Appends the specified exception to the exceptions that were suppressed in order to deliver this exception. This method is thread-safe and typically called (automatically and implicitly) by the try-with-resources statement.
>
> The suppression behavior is enabled unless disabled via a constructor. When suppression is disabled, this method does nothing other than to validate its argument.
>
> Note that when one exception causes another exception, the first exception is usually caught and then the second exception is thrown in response. In other words, there is a causal connection between the two exceptions. In contrast, there are situations where two independent exceptions can be thrown in sibling code blocks, in particular in the try block of a try-with-resources statement and the compiler-generated finally block which closes the resource. In these situations, only one of the thrown exceptions can be propagated. In the try-with-resources statement, when there are two such exceptions, the exception originating from the try block is propagated and the exception from the finally block is added to the list of exceptions suppressed by the exception from the try block. As an exception unwinds the stack, it can accumulate multiple suppressed exceptions.
>
> An exception may have suppressed exceptions while also being caused by another exception. Whether or not an exception has a cause is semantically known at the time of its creation, unlike whether or not an exception will suppress other exceptions which is typically only determined after an exception is thrown.
>
> Note that programmer written code is also able to take advantage of calling this method in situations where there are multiple sibling exceptions and only one can be propagated.

Note that last paragraph, which seems to suit your case.

Comment: _[...] whether or not an exception will suppress other exceptions [...] is typically only determined after an exception is thrown._ I imagine this will not be the case when multiple suppressed exceptions are collected from parallel runs.

Comment: @GOTO0 - That would depend on what is doing the collecting.  I see nothing in the spec that disallows collecting and adding an exception thrown on a different stack.

Answer (score 24):

Exceptions and their causes are always only a 1:1 thing: you can throw *one* exception and each exception can only have *one* cause (which can again have one cause ...).

That could be considered a design fault, especially when considering multi-threaded behaviour as you described.

That's one of the reasons why Java 7 added [`addSuppressed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) to throwable which can basically attach an arbitrary amount of exceptions to a single other one (the other primary motivation was try-with-resources which needed a way to handle exceptions in the finally block without silently dropping them).

So basically when you have 1 exception that causes your process to fail, you add that one as the cause of your higher-level exception, and if you have any more, then you add those to the original one using `addSuppressed`. The idea is that that first exception "supressed" the others becoming a member of the "real exception chain".

Sample code:

```
Exception exception = null;
for (Foobar foobar : foobars) {
  try {
    foobar.frobnicate();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    if (exception == null) {
      exception = ex;
    } else {
      exception.addSuppressed(ex);
    }
  }
}
if (exception != null) {
  throw new SomethingWentWrongException(exception);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it quite the way you suggest, unless one of the underlying exceptions can really be singled out as the "main" one. If you just arbitrarily pick one of the exceptions as the main one and the others as suppressed, you're _inviting_ a caller to ignore the suppressed exceptions and just report the main one — even if the "main" exception is a TypoInUserInputException and one of the suppressed ones is a DatabaseCorruptedException.

Comment: … Instead, I'd mark _all_ the underlying exceptions as suppressed by the SomethingWentWrongException, and give that exception a message clearly indicating that one or more suppressed exceptions _should_ follow, e.g. something like "*X* out of *Y* tasks failed, see list of failures below".

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Exceptions wrapper for such cases like that:
(You can also concatenate the user messages, or enhance the class for your needs. When logged, you will get the stack trace for all exceptions. )

```
    public static class MyException extends Exception {

    private List<Throwable> additionalSuppressed = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public MyException(String message, Throwable... causes) {
        super(message, causes.length > 0 ? causes[0] : null);
        for (int i = 1; i < causes.length; i++) {
            if (causes[i] != null && !isSuppressedAlready(this, causes[i])) {
                additionalSuppressed.add(causes[i]);
            }
        }
        for (Throwable suppressed : additionalSuppressed) {
            this.addSuppressed(suppressed);
        }
    }

    private boolean isSuppressedAlready(Throwable cause, Throwable toCheck) {
        if (cause == toCheck) {
            return true; // Direct reference equality check to avoid circular references
        }
        for (Throwable suppressed : cause.getSuppressed()) {
            if (suppressed == toCheck || isSuppressedAlready(suppressed, toCheck)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addSuppressedException(Throwable exception) {
        if (exception != null && !isSuppressedAlready(this, exception)) {
            additionalSuppressed.add(exception);
            this.addSuppressed(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a testing method:

```
    public static void throwOne() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("0ne");
}

public static void throwTwo() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Two");
}


public static void testException() throws MyException {
    
    try {
        throwOne();
        
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        try {
            throwTwo();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // take out the next line code (it is added just for testing circular references)
            e2.addSuppressed(e1); // No need to add this again here, we are only making sure code works without causing circular references in case some other parts of your handling routines adds a suppressed exception twice...
            throw new MyException("2 failed", e2, e1);
        }
        throw new MyException("1 failed", e1);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
    com.test.Test$MyException: 2 failed
    at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:82)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Two
    at com.test.Test.throwTwo(Test.java:66)
    at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:79)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: 0ne
        at com.test.Test.throwOne(Test.java:62)
        at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:75)
        ... 1 more
```

To gather the full exception context in a finally block, you have to do a little extra coding (When dealing with exceptions in a finally block, it's important to remember that if both try and finally blocks throw exceptions, the one from the finally block will propagate, and the one from the try block will be suppressed.) Here is a sample of how the ExceptionWrapper class can be used:

```
    public static void throwOne() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("0ne");
}

public static void throwTwo() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Two");
}

public static void throwThree() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Three");
}

public static void testException() throws MyException {
    MyException pendingException = null;

    try {
        throwOne();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        try {
            throwTwo();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            pendingException = new MyException("2 failed", e2, e1);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            throwThree();
        } catch (Exception e3) {
            if (pendingException != null) {
                pendingException.addSuppressedException(e3);
                throw pendingException;
            } else {
                throw new MyException("3 failed", e3);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pendingException != null) {
        throw pendingException;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
com.test.Test$MyException: 2 failed
at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:99)
at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: 0ne
    at com.test.Test.throwOne(Test.java:79)
    at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:94)
    ... 1 more
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: Three
    at com.test.Test.throwThree(Test.java:87)
    at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:103)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Two
at com.test.Test.throwTwo(Test.java:83)
at com.test.Test.testException(Test.java:97)
... 1 more
```