# Suppressed exception disappeared when using finally?

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

Here's the code.

```
public class TestTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            run();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            printSuppressedExceptions(e);
        }
    }

    public static void printSuppressedExceptions(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println("suppressed exceptions: " + t.getSuppressed().length);
    }

    public static void run() throws Exception {
        try(MyResource r = new MyResource("resource");) {
            System.out.println("try");
            System.getProperty("").length(); // throws illegalArgumentException
        } catch(Exception e) {
            printSuppressedExceptions(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            new MyResource("finally").close();
        }
    }   
}

class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {
    private final String name;

    public MyResource(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("exception" + " from " + this.name);
    }
}
```

Since exception thrown from try block suppressed the exception from resource, I got "suppressed exceptions: 1" at first which was understandable. But when an exception was thrown from finally, it seemed like all suppressed exceptions disappeared because I got "java.lang.Exception: exception from finally" followed by "suppressed exceptions: 0" which I think it should be **1**.
I browsed the Java tutorials and it definitely says

> However, in this example, if the methods readLine and close both throw exceptions, then the method readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock throws the exception thrown from the finally block; the exception thrown from the try block is suppressed.

From [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

How could it happen?

Comment: Just speculating: Could it be that it is, because there are 2 exceptions thrown? I expect one from `r.close()` when try-with-resources closes r and another one from the additional object created and closed in the finally block ...

Comment: Also, the cited text refers to an example of prior Java 7 usage of the `try{ read() }finally{ close() }`. I suggest you read the whole paragraph and go on reading the "Suppressed Exceptions" Paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. I think @tuempl just solved my confusion. _But this time the word suppressed used in the java tutorial does not stand for "suppressed and added to the actually thrown exception" but "suppressed and lost to nirvana"._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that does what you would expect:

```
public class TestTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            run();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            printSuppressedExceptions(e);
        }
    }

    public static void printSuppressedExceptions(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println("suppressed exceptions (" + t.getSuppressed().length + "):");
        for (Throwable suppressed : t.getSuppressed()) {
            System.out.println("  - " + suppressed);
        }
    }

    public static void run() throws Exception {
        Exception exceptionFromCatch = null;
        try(MyResource r = new MyResource("resource");) {
            System.out.println("try");
            System.getProperty("").length(); // throws illegalArgumentException
        } catch(Exception e) {
            exceptionFromCatch = e;
            printSuppressedExceptions(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                new MyResource("finally").close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (exceptionFromCatch!=null) {
                    e.addSuppressed(exceptionFromCatch);
                }
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }   
}

class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {
    private final String name;

    public MyResource(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("exception" + " from " + this.name);
    }
}
```

So lets go trough the try-with-resource part of your code (as introduced in JDK 1.7.0) and see what happens (see [What is the Java 7 try-with-resources bytecode equivalent using try-catch-finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860137/what-is-the-java-7-try-with-resources-bytecode-equivalent-using-try-catch-finall) for more details):

- the try-with-resource block `MyResource r = new MyResource("resource")` is executed
- the try block is executed and throws an `IllegalArgumentException`
- the try-with-resource block calls `close()` for all resources (in your example only one)
- `close()` throws an exception, but since the exception from the try block has priority the exception from thrown by `close()` is suppressed and added via `addSuppressed(..)`

So that part works like you expected from reading the tutorial.

And now the try-catch-finally part of your code (as in JDK 1.6 and earlier):

- the try block is executed and throws an `IllegalArgumentException`
- (the catch block behaves the same way as if there was no catch block)
- the finally block is executed and throws an Exception
- the exception from the finally block has priority and the one from the try block is suppressed

But this time the word ***suppressed*** used in the java tutorial does not stand for *"suppressed and added to the actually thrown exception"* but *"suppressed and lost to nirvana"*. So it still behaves as in JDK 1.6 and earlier and does not make use of the newly introduced `addSuppressed(..)` `getSuppressed()` functionality. That's the reason it doesn't behave like you expected.

---

I would argue the behaviour you expected wouldn't be logical either. I would like it to behave like this:

```
...
        } finally {
            try {
                new MyResource("finally").close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (exceptionFromCatch!=null) {
                    exceptionFromCatch.addSuppressed(e);
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
...
```

That would always give priority to the exception from the try block (as implemented with the new try-with-resource feature) and add the exception from the catch block as suppressed to the list. But that would break compatibility with JDK 1.6, so I guess that's the reason why it doesn't behave like that.

Comment: Aha, just thought all suppressed exceptions would be added into the actually thrown exception since 1.7 which turned to be totally wrong.